# Adding a directory to user PATH doesn't work?

Tags: windows-7, path

I just installed gvim on my Windows system (it's on C:\gvim, anyway). Then I add C:\gvim\vim73\ on the user PATH, not the system PATH. After that, I tried to invoke vim from the command prompt. Nope, it didn't work. So I removed gvim directory from the user PATH to system PATH. It did work.

I'm still curious, so I do a "echo %PATH%", and the result is everything from the system PATH.

My understanding is the system PATH has a higher priority than user, so Windows first will try to search the system PATH, and after that the users'. So it should have worked, but it didn't.

Comment: Did you log the user out and back in after making the original change? It won’t take until the user profile is reloaded.

Comment: User environment variables always override system ones. But `%PATH%` is an exception - Windows will merge system and user values, in that order. So you're right about its priority.

Answer (score 8):

### You're not actually setting any environment variables of any form when you modify the registry.

Environment variables are not kept in the registry. What is kept in the registry is a *template*, from which programs like Windows Explorer (re-)construct their environment variables when notified to do so. Actual environment variables are per-process and are stored in each process' own address space, initially inherited from its parent process and modifiable thereafter at the process' whim.  The programs like Windows Explorer participate in a voluntary protocol, whereby they will re-read the template, and update *their own per-process environment* whenever [a Windows message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms725497(VS.85).aspx) is broadcast to all (top-level) windows on a desktop.

Many Win32 programs *do not participate in this voluntary protocol*.  Microsoft's command interpreter is one such program.  To modify an environment variable within a running Microsoft command interpreter process, one uses *the ordinary command interpreter commands* for modifying environment variables, such as `SET`, `DPATH`, and `PATH`.  The modified environment will be inherited by every process that the command interpreter spawns.

Similarly, the modified environment in a Windows Explorer process is only inherited by processes that are spawned by Windows Explorer *after* it has received the message and re-read the template.  The environment variables of an already running process are not affected by modifications made by other processes to *their own* environment variables.  An *already running* Microsoft command interpreter won't magically gain a changed environment from the Windows Explorer process that spawned it before the change.

Other command interpreters differ.  [JP Software's TCC](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), for example, itself participates in the voluntary protocol.  It will recognize the Windows message, and update its own per-process environment from the template in the registry, when its ["Update Environment on System Change"](http://jpsoft.com./help/index.htm?inistartupdlg.htm) setting is enabled.